# UITableView is populated with same set of values each time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using the following code to load data into tableview. Following is my code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"any-cell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"any-cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

        UILabel* productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30); // for example
        productAmountTextLabel.tag = 10000; // any number
        [cell.contentView addSubview:productAmountTextLabel];
    }


    UILabel* lbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 10000];
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lbl.text = [device valueForKey:@"amount"];
    return cell;
}
```

The problem is that each cells of tableview displays same value. Why is that so?

Following is my viewdDidLoad method,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    segmentedControl = [[URBSegmentedControl alloc]initWithTitles:titles icons:icons];


    NSError *Error = nil;
    APIRequest *apiRequest = [[APIRequest alloc]init];
    [apiRequest getPendingData];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&Error];

    amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSManagedObjectContext * info in fetchedObjects)

    {

        [amountArray addObject:[info valueForKey:@"amount"]];

    }

    segmentedControl.segmentBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:86/255.0f green:199/255.0f blue:188/255.0f alpha:1];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.devices);


    self.completedOrdersTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Im fetching values over there and adding it to an array.

within  `viewDidLoad` , it has unique set of datas but within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it has sameset of datas being repeated multiple times.

Comment: Try logging your `self.devices` array and look at its content.

Comment: it contains only one set of data being repeated multiple times

Comment: So you're trying to display the same data multiple times ?

Comment: within `viewDidLoad` method, it `self.devices` has two unique datas. But within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it contains same set of data being repeated multiple times.

Comment: no im trying to display two different datas.

Comment: Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method looks fine, if the `devices` array has changed it's not in this method.

Comment: in `viewDidLoad` method, it has unique datas but in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it contains same data multiple times. How can I rectify this?

Comment: We can't know where this array was changed from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath `code. Look at very line where it is changed or its content change and try looking for the issue.

Comment: i have posted the viewDidLoadMethod

Comment: `devices`looks properly initialized, but according to your comments it was always the case. What you must find is when it is changed.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called multiple times. Is that could be the reason?

Comment: No, its totally normal, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called at least once per row.

Comment: I have a file called, APIRequst.m within which there are two methods, `getPendingData`,`pendingShipmentDetails`. `getPendingData` invokes `pendingShipmentDetails` after deleting all existing values in coredata db.  once if records are deleted, it adds new datas to the db.In MyOrdersController.m, Im invoking `getPendingData` within viewDidLoad method and the rest of the code goes as I have posted.

Comment: i tried logging amountArray within `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it contains two unique datas

Comment: any ideas if I can use amountArray to set data?

Comment: You can, but that doesn't resolve the issue of the array being edited without you know it.

Comment: in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` , I have to return 1 and in  `numberOfRowsInSection:` , I have to return `[self.devices count]` but I was doing vice versa....lol

Comment: ok i will do it then

Comment: Nice catch, `indexPath.row` was always 0 then. So devices array wasn't modified when you used it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Did you actually logged it to test ?

Comment: yes bro...i logged it to test. Please check my answer...somehow we have debugged it :)

Comment: I'm glad you catch it. Going from Android framework to iOS doesn't look easy at all (as the inverse, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Michaël Azevedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1878781/micha%C3%ABl-azevedo) for helping me debug the issue. The way I debugged  was, I tried logging indexpath.row and indexpath.section. I notices that, row is always 0 and section is dynamic (value changes).

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i was setting the values with reference to indexpath.row which is going to 0 always.

Then i changed my code as follows,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.devices count];

}
```

so now the `numberOfRowsInSection` will not be zero anymore. Hence while accessing it, It wont be fetching the same set of value of multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be your array named "self.devices". All your label.text is coming from your device model. You can try printing self.devices to take a look at each object in your array.

Comment: i tried printing it.   in `viewDidLoad` method, it has unique datas but in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it contains same data multiple times.